# Could I get information about payments by plastic card via apis (for example like Visa API)?

Tags: payment, finance, mastercard

Could I get any iformation or notification about payments by plastic card via APIs? If yes, how?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

usually you can find this information in the relevant website - like this one: https://developer.mastercard.com/product/masterpass

But you may find it easier to integrate with a Payment Gateway that offers API solutions - take a look at the BlueSnap documentation for example - I think it'll give you the solutions you're after..
https://developers.bluesnap.com/

Comment: This APIs provide functionality to make payments. I didn't find any information about payments meta information. I think, this information is protected and private. Thanks for answer.